# Link to the product from the shopping cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

Is it possible to link to the product from the shopping cart?
Something like `{{ item.url }}` within `cart.lineItems`

When using `{{ product.url }}` looping through `craft.commerce.products` I am getting a list with all product entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://craftcommerce.com/support/accessing-product-info-from-order)

```
{% for item in order.lineItems %}
    {% set variant = item.purchasable %}
    {% set product = variant.product %}
    <li>{{ product.getUrl() }} - {{ variant.sku }} ({{ item.qty }})</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ item.purchasable.url }}
```

should do it.

Comment: If you are using products and variants only.

Comment: Thanks a loot Luke. It works really well, with a little correction: {{ item.purchasa**b**le.url }}